# Supporting group editing of same shapefile with open source tools?

Tags: qgis, postgis, shapefile, spatial-database

We are a small (~5) group working on a single, shared shapefile. The current workflow is that each one of us does the editing on a designated attribute field, on his local copy, then exports the attributes table as a CSV file, which will be joined with shapefiles on all the other copies.

Obviously it is quite inefficient and, when comes to adding a feature or multiple people working on the same attribute, very error-prone.

How can we manage this situation?

Comment: @AndreJ Then, presumably, shapefile would be stored in a POSTGIS database on of the computers. how are the other ones going to access this database? I'm not that familiar with databases.

Comment: @AndreJ If this process is too complicated to post as an answer or comment, would you please suggest a few keywords that I can lookup?

Comment: The database is shared on one computer (or a network server if you have), and every authenticated user can access it. Same as Microsft Access for normal databases does. The database itself manages the database integrity, like locking a table that is in edit mode, and merging unsaved and saved data. I have not tried to share my own postgis database (only access databases so far), but it should work the same way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need full database support with simultaneous user access handling, `POSTGIS` would be the best choice.

As a first step on remote postgis access, see [Connnect to PostGIS db using QGIS - when not on localhost](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58446/connnect-to-postgis-db-using-qgis-when-not-on-localhost)

See also: [Best choice for building static maps: PostGIS, SpatiaLite or Shapefile?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83918/best-choice-for-building-static-maps-postgis-spatialite-or-shapefile)